# Defining a global variable, and including functions that require it?

Tags: php

I have six functions that require a global variable.  In an attempt to reduce redundancy, I wrote a new function that is triggered rather than triggering all six.  This one function has a global $var that is required by the other functions.

So, it looks like this

```
function one_function_for_the_rest() {
    global $importantVar;

    functionOne();
    functionTwo();
    functionThree();

}
```

but the global variable is not being seen by the called functions.  Am I doing this incorrectly, or is this a limitation I was not aware of?

Comment: Because these three functions has got their own scope so they don't see your `$importantVar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not doing it correctly as the variable is defined when `on_function_for...` is called. An easier way for this would be just to  have `$importantVar;` at the start of the code.

Or wrap your functions inside a class and put the variable inside the class.

e: so basically do : `function myFunc($important) { stuff }` and when calling the function do `myFunc($importantVar)`

example :

```
$asd = "lol";
class myclass {

    public function lol($asd) {
        echo $asd;
    }
}
$obj = new myclass;
$obj->lol($asd);
```

Comment: I like the class idea, I believe I will use it.  Thanks!

Comment: remember to pass it in the function also like function myfunction ($importantvar)

Comment: @GregL If this (or another) answer helped you solve the original question, please consider marking it as accepted

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing it correctly. *Each* function either needs to use the `global` scope identifier, like `global $importantVar;`, or have `$importantVar` passed as a parameter. Otherwise, the other functions don't have `$importantVar` in their respective scopes.

Simply calling a function from within `one_function_for_the_rest` does not tell that other function anything about global variables or variables used in `one_function_for_the_rest`. In technical terms, your function calls do not bring `$importantVar` into the respective scopes of `functionOne`, `functionTwo`, or `functionThree`.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I was considering the option of using a superglobal. But seems smarter to just redeclare the global. Redundancy bugs me.

Answer (score 1):

PHP does not have the same scoping rules as most other languages have. That is the downside to not having to declare variables with `var` as in JavaScript or other similar constructs.

Basically in PHP, every function used is only available in that function. There are three exceptions:

1. The `global` keyword
2. The `$this` variable inside objects. This one is also "magic" as it's also available inside anonymous functions defined inside a class.
3. When declaring an anonymous functions you can bind variables to it using `use`.